# Pop current view from stack and push new one Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

I have an app where I am in a registration form and when the user clicks submit, it takes them to the previous page. When on the previous page, if the user clicks back it takes them back to the registration page which I do not want. How can I remove that registration view from the stack?

This is my current approach:

```
//inside MyRegistrationController button press
MyPreviousController SVC = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MyPreviousController") as MyPreviousController;
            if(SVC != null){
                SVC.offender = offender;


                //var viewControllers = this.NavigationController.ViewControllers;
                //viewControllers[viewControllers.Length - 1].View.RemoveFromSuperview();
                //this.NavigationController.ViewControllers = viewControllers;

                this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController(SVC, true);
            }
```

This current approach does something weird with the stack, who I click the button on `MyRegistrationController` I go to the `MyPreviousController`(un updated) then quickly go to an updated version of `MyPreviousController` back to an updated version of `MyPreviousController` and then if I click the back button I go back to `MyPreviousController`

Comment: Using the `NavigationController.ViewControllers` will work. The problem with your commented out code is that you're just removing the View from the ViewController. You can remove the ViewController from the array, set the ViewControllers property to the updated array, and then it won't be in the stack anymore.

Comment: My problem is that there are no `UIViewController[]` remove functions so I'm not sure how to go about removing elements from that array

Comment: Arrays don't allow you to add or remove elements - they are a fixed size data structure. It's pretty easy to do with LINQ - add `using System.Linq;` at the top, then you can do `viewControllers.Take(viewControllers.Length 1).ToArray();` and it will create a new array without the last ViewController from the original array.

Comment: @DylanS thanks for that, but now clicking the button just keeps me on the same page. how would I go back to the previous controller after setting the `viewControllers`? using `push()` right after those statements seems to restore ViewControllers

Answer (score 3):

Okay I ended up getting it to work. My issue ended up being two-fold. One I needed to pop off the view, and two I needed my table data in `MyPreviousController` to reload(an issue I did not bring up). So I needed to do the following:

To simply pop off the current controller I needed to just say:

```
//inside MyRegistrationController button press
MyPreviousController SVC = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MyPreviousController") as MyPreviousController;
        if(SVC != null){
            SVC.offender = offender;

            this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
}
```

However doing just this caused my table in `MyPrevious` to not get updated. So i needed to put this in the `MyPreviousController.cs`:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
        InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
            TableView.Source = source;
            TableView.ReloadData();
        });
    }
```

and that successfully updated the table and removed the registration view

Comment: Assuming `offender` is a property on the view controller, by not just put the code from `ViewWillAppear` into the setter of the property? `ViewWillAppear` happens everytime the view is shown. So when it opens the first time, or when the user comes back to it. Just make sure you aren't calling `ReloadData` on the table view in something like the `ViewDidLoad` also, or else it will be updating the table view twice.